# How to create txt frequency counter with all letters (a-z) in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file named textf that looks something like the following:

```
rxgmgcwbd c qcyurr bkxgmq, lwrg grru rrwxtam rwgzwt am quyam cv avrrgdwkxgcr.iwxbdamcz xdalguj qarc ram av vcmfwgmgum. yw'g
```

I want to do a frequency count for each letter in the text file but I want it with the condition that if a letter does not appear in the text, it should have a key:value pair with value 0. For example if z was not in the text it should look something like 'z': 0 and so on for all letters (a to z). I did the following code:

```
import string  
from collections import Counter 
with open("textf.txt") as tf: 
    letter = tf.read()
letter_count = Counter(letter.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)))
print("Frequency count of letter:","\n",letter_count)
```

But the output looks something like this:

```
Counter({' ': 110, 'r': 12, 'c': 88, 'a': 55, 'g': 57, 'w': 76, 'm': 76, 'x': 72, 'u': 70, 'q': 41, 'y': 40, 'j': 36, 'l': 32, 'b': 18, 'd': 28, 'v': 27, 'k': 22, 't': 19, 'f': 18, 'z': 16, 'i': 7})
```

I am trying to make it so that the space count `' ': 110` is not shown and that I have all the letters(a-z) and when the letter does not appear in the text that my result prints something like `'n': 0` and so on. Any ideas or suggestions of how I could make this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do this is to make a normal dict from your Counter, using the lowercase letters as the keys of the new dict. We use the `dict.get` method to supply a default value of zero for missing letters.

```
import string  
from collections import Counter 

letter = "rxgmgcwbd c qcyurr bkxgmq, lwrg grru rrwxtam rwgzwt am quyam cv avrrgdwkxgcr.iwxbdamcz xdalguj qarc ram av vcmfwgmgum. yw'g"

letter_count = Counter(letter.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)))
letter_count = {k: letter_count.get(k, 0) for k in string.ascii_lowercase}
print("Frequency count of letter:\n", letter_count)
```

**output**

```
Frequency count of letter:
 {'a': 9, 'b': 3, 'c': 8, 'd': 4, 'e': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 12, 'h': 0, 'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'k': 2, 'l': 2, 'm': 10, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 4, 'r': 14, 's': 0, 't': 2, 'u': 5, 'v': 4, 'w': 9, 'x': 6, 'y': 3, 'z': 2}
```

If you do this in Python 3.6+ you get the side-benefit that the new dict is alphabetically sorted (although that behaviour is currently just an implementation detail that should not be relied upon).

---

As  user2357112 mentions in the comments, we don't need to use `letter_count.get(k, 0)`, since a Counter automatically returns zero if we try to read the value of a non-existent key. So that dict comprehension can be changed to

```
letter_count = {k: letter_count[k] for k in string.ascii_lowercase}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I did not know of the method dict.get. This will be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `If you do this in Python 3.6+ you get the side-benefit that the new dict is alphabetically sorted.` - This is not true. It may coincidentally come back in alphabetic order, depending on implementation details. But the language spec has not changed. If you must have them ordered, you still need to use OrderedDict

Comment: `collections.Counter` already defaults to a count of 0 for not-present keys, so you don't need to do `letter_count.get(k, 0)`. You can just do `letter_count[k]`.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, of course. Thanks for that info, I'll add it to my answer shortly.

Comment: @Daenyth Sure, it's _currently_ just an implementation detail that CPython 3.6 maintains the insertion order of dictionaries. However, it's quite unlikely that dicts will revert to the old behaviour in future versions. But yes, if you want to guarantee that the resulting collection is ordered you need to use an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this like so:

```
x = "rxgmgcwbd c qcyurr bkxgmq, lwrg grru rrwxtam rwgzwt am quyam cv avrrgdwkxgcr.iwxbdamcz xdalguj qarc ram av vcmfwgmgum. yw'g"

import string

freq = {i:0 for i in string.ascii_lowercase}
for i in x:
    if i in freq:
        freq[i] += 1
```

You can also replace the for-loop with a *dictionary-comprehension* (**though** it's ***inefficient*** for what we are trying to do since it uses `count` - but added as a way *just for reference*):

```
freq = {i:x.count(i) for i in freq}
```

This will give as a result:

```
{'a': 9, 'c': 8, 'b': 3, 'e': 0, 'd': 4, 'g': 12, 'f': 1, 'i': 1, 'h': 0, 'k': 2, 'j': 1, 'm': 10, 'l': 2, 'o': 0, 'n': 0, 'q': 4, 'p': 0, 's': 0, 'r': 14, 'u': 5, 't': 2, 'w': 9, 'v': 4, 'y': 3, 'x': 6, 'z': 2}
```

Comment: You are missing 6 letters.

Comment: @MartinEvans thx I didn't notice you are right - I'll update accordingly...

Comment: You could make this a little faster by building a set from `string.ascii_lowercase`. And it's probably a good idea to avoid that `KeyError`. `try...except` in Python is quite efficient, and faster than equivalent `if`-based code if the exception isn't raised, but if the exception does get raised more than around 5-10% of the time, then it can be quite slow.

Comment: @PM2Ring thx, I didn't know that the number of exceptions play such important role in the speed. I updated the answer such that it doesn't use exceptions at all. Also instead of sets I used `keys()` which I suppose does the same thing. Thanks, again for the great advice!

Comment: Well, it's not the number of exceptions raised, per se. It's just that `try..except` is _really_ fast if everything's ok, but it's rather slow when an exception actually does get raised, and that 5-10% figure I quoted above is just a rough average derived from various tests with "typical" data.

Comment: And yes, using `keys()` is perfectly fine. It's not quite a set, but the docs call it set-like, and it supports a variety of useful set operations.

Comment: Calling `keys` is pointless, and calling `count` requires 26 passes over the string.

Comment: @user2357112 yes I know `count` is inefficient for what we are trying to do - that's why I didn't include it in my original answer but just added it as an other way just for reference.Thanks, though for mentioning it - I'll update my answer accordingly :) As for `.keys()` - yes can also be omitted but really doesn't affect performance!

Comment: `keys` doesn't affect performance (much) on Python 3, but it can be catastrophic on Python 2. Even if this code is only intended for Python 3, it's better to avoid `keys`, so people learning by example (or copy-pasting) don't learn bad habits for Python 2 without realizing the version differences.

Answer (score 7):

You can initialise your `Counter()` with a dictionary. In this case a dictionary comprehension is used to initialize all the lowercase letters to zero.

Using `update()` with the `letter` will then add to these existing values:

```
from collections import Counter 

letter = "hello world "
letter_counts = Counter({l:0 for l in string.ascii_lowercase})
letter_counts.update(letter.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation + ' ')))

print(letter_counts)
```

Giving you:

```
Counter({'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'd': 1, 'w': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 1, 'p': 0, 'c': 0, 'j': 0, 'x': 0, 't': 0, 'g': 0, 'n': 0, 'f': 0, 'u': 0, 'm': 0, 'q': 0, 'z': 0, 's': 0, 'y': 0, 'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'i': 0, 'k': 0, 'v': 0})
```

To get rid of the space, add it to the punctuation string.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
import string
from collections import defaultdict

row="rxgmgcwbd c qcyurr bkxgmq, lwrg grru rrwxtam rwgzwt am quyam cv avrrgdwkxgcr.iwxbdamcz xdalguj qarc ram av vcmfwgmgum. yw'g"
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
stats = defaultdict(list)
for l in letters:
    stats[l]=0
for l in row:
    if l.isalpha():
        stats[l]+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.fromkeys` to init dictionary with default 0 value for missing letters. And then update this dictionary:

```
import string

x = "rxgmgcwbd c qcyurr bkxgmq, lwrg grru rrwxtam rwgzwt am quyam cv avrrgdwkxgcr.iwxbdamcz xdalguj qarc ram av vcmfwgmgum. yw'g"

letter_count = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
for c in x:
    if c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        letter_count[c] += 1
print letter_count
```

Output:

```
{'a': 9, 'c': 8, 'b': 3, 'e': 0, 'd': 4, 'g': 12, 'f': 1, 'i': 1, 'h': 0, 'k': 2, 'j': 1, 'm': 10, 'l': 2, 'o': 0, 'n': 0, 'q': 4, 'p': 0, 's': 0, 'r': 14, 'u': 5, 't': 2, 'w': 9, 'v': 4, 'y': 3, 'x': 6, 'z': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... that my result prints something like ...

The other answers focus on choosing a different data structure, but to me it sounds like you already chose the right data structure, `Counter`, and just want to *display* the result nicely. So something like this would do:

```
display_str = "{" + ", ".join("'{}': {}".format(x, letter_count[x]) for x in string.ascii_lowercase) + "}"
print("Frequency count of letter:", display_str, sep="\n")
```